# Counting ahead of a specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, count

I'm trying to find a way to count elements that are a head of a certain class name. I have the following:

```
$('.active').each(function(index,item){
  var nextDiv = $(item).next();
  var followingDiv = $(nextDiv).next('a');
  $(item).wrap("<div id='window" + index + "'></div>");
  $("#window"+index).append(nextDiv).append(followingDiv);
});
```

This works all right, it only grabs two elements which are `'a'` tags ahead of the active item which in this case is `'.active'` and wraps them in a `div` called `'window'`.

What i want to figure out how to do is add more than just two elements a head of the active class and store that in a variable instead of making 10 variables that keep say `.next('a').next('a') etc...` Then having to append all those newly created variables like:

`$("#window"+index).append(nextDiv).append(followingDiv).append(another-a).append(another-a-again)`...

I believe there should be a simpler way to count a specified number of elements a head of a certain class name without having to recreate lots of variables.

Comment: I am not really sure what you are doing here. can you put a demo on http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [**`.nextAll()`** <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

> Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
var as = $(this).nextAll('a');
```

**Update:** Forgot the max limit. You can use [`.slice()` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) for that:

```
var as = $(this).nextAll('a').slice(0,10);
```

Your whole code would be:

```
$('.active').each(function(index,item){
  $(this).nextAll('a').slice(0,10)
      .add(this)
      .wrap("<div id='window" + index + "'></div>");
});
```

Maybe [`nextUntil` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) is also interesting for you if you want to group all `.active` elements with their following links.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) (or [nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), depending on which direction you mean by "ahead").

You could probably do something like:

```
$('.active').each(function(index, item) {
  $(this).prevAll().each(function(prevIndex, prevItem) {
    if (prevIndex < 10) {
      // ... do something with prevItem
    }
  });
});
```

You might have to (e.g.) reverse the order to get the elements immediately before `.active`